# Google Analytics tracking for hybrid Cordova app

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to implement google analytics into Hybrid cordova app.
following google documentation from below link
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Initial configuration doesnt even works.I cant see any events logging to Google Analytics dashboard.Have anyone used this analytics.js for Cordova apps?

Comment: Can you show your effort? And be more specific.. like do you get any errors on the console? I am using successfully google analytics. There is also a cordova plugin for that. check [here](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin)

Comment: I am using
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
above to configure analytics.js from index.html with my tracking Id
Event tracking is done on one of js
ga('send', 'event', 'app', 'Login success');

Comment: with this i am not getting any errors in console.How can i debug this scenerio?How can i be sure if analytics.js is been loaded in app.
I actually cant use any third party Cordova plugins in my app

Comment: You can debug a cordova app using chrome if your are developing for Android and Safari for iPhone. To debug for android, open chrome and type `chrome:inspect`, connect your device and then select it from the list and then open your application on your phone and select it from the list on chrome. This will open the debugging tool. For iPhone open safari and iPhone simulator and run your app. On safari select `Develop->iPhone Simulator`. This will open the debugging tool. There you will see all the errors you get and more that will help you debug your app

Comment: I know about these debugging method.but console here doesn't report anything about Google analytics.how can I know what going wrong with analytics.js

Comment: Have you whitelisted google analytics connections? If you are using cordova 5+ then you have to set the content security policy (check this section on Github page linked at the end) by using the whitelist plugin that is installed by default when you create a new app. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). I thing this is your problem

Comment: Can you use Android and IOS native code? or just javascript?

Comment: i added whitelisting in config.xml as below
<access origin="*://*.google-analytics.com/*" subdomains="true" />
Still i cant see any analytics on google.Does it take some time for analytics to prapogate to google analytics dashboard.I am even watching Real time tab, but no logs there.
Is i am doing something wrong with whitelisting?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found out that Google account was getting effected with spam bots
I was getting some random spam records in analytics.
So I found of that the account with tracking I'd ending with '1' is more likely to be effected by spam.I created a new property into same account which gives tracking id ending with '2'.I am now getting all of my records recorded properly in analytics.